# Unable to get FastMM4 to work with Delphi 7 application protected using ASProtect

Tags: delphi, memory-management, fastmm

I'm getting this error, "FastMM4 cannot install since memory has already been allocated through the default memory manager". I'm using ASProtect and Eurekalog for my Delphi 7 application (there's no problems with Eurekalog though). I've already placed FastMM4 as the first unit as required.

Later I found out that ASProtect can execute a DLL before running the application.

> *External User Code*Since this version, ASProtect implements an external dynamic library > usage feature. This might be very useful if you want you own code to be executed by
>   ASProtect befor main application starting. You should provide ASProtect with the full 
>   path to the selected DLL. This library will be added to ASProtect code at the protection > step. There is only one function which will be executed by ASprotect at the run-time 
>   before running the main application.
>
> Function declaration:
>
> Delphi:
>   function RunApplication() : Boolean; export;
>
> If function result is TRUE, ASProtect will start main application, otherwise error 
>   message occures. 
>   Warning: If you want to get access to the resources of your DLL use DialogBoxIndirect or > CreateDialogBoxInderect class APIs. All other WinAPI functions (such as FindResorceA, 
>   LoadResource, etc) might not working correctly and returns error results.

So, I created a DLL with the following but this doesn't help.

> library fastmem;
>
> uses
>   FastMM4 in 'FastMM4.pas',
>   SysUtils,dialogs,
>   Classes;
>
> {$R *.res}
>
> begin
>   showmessage('ok!');
>   end.

After that, I run my application, and it displays 'OK' messagebox before showing the "FastMM4 cannot install since memory has already been allocated through the default memory manager" error.

Any thoughts of how I can solve this problem? Can I disable Delphi's default memory manager? Thanks.  :)

Note: ASProtect no longer provides forum support.

Comment: The DLL won't help, as it has no effect on the memory manager used by your application. As far as disabling Delphi's default memory manager, the way to do that is by installing another one before Delphi's, which is what happens with FastMM4 if you place it as the first unit in your **project** file (not the main form's source, but the **project** source). Is that where you're using it?

Comment: Is there any Sharemem going on?

Comment: @Ken White - Yes, I've placed FastMM4 as the first unit, but ASProtect creates a wrapper around the application, which is how it protects and compress the app.

Comment: @David Heffernan - I checked, there's no Sharemen.  Thanks.

Comment: What did tech support for ASProtect say when you asked them?

Comment: @Joshua, then there are only three solutions: 1) Stop using FastMM4,  2) stop using ASPack, or 3) convince the folks at ASPack to provide you a version that uses the same version of FastMM4 as you're wanting to use.

Comment: @Ken White - ASProtect appeared to have gone dormant after the original developer sold the software to the company.  They no longer provide forum support (yes, the form is still there but no support provided) and I'm not even sure if they are still doing development.  I've decided to use ASProtect on a DLL which will contain some of my critical app functions.  The main app will use FastMM4 but will not use ASProtect.  Not sure if this will work though.  :)